# Kube-apiserver crashing

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to create a kubernetes cluster on my local machine.
I created 3 vm's (two master and a slave). 
I am using kubespray(v2.15.0) to create my cluster, But my kube-apiserver contianer keeps crashing with following error:

```
2021-03-03T10:33:06.41276414Z stderr F F0303 10:33:06.408597       1 sample_and_watermark.go:182] Time went backwards from 2021-03-03T10:33:06.408588954Z to 2021-03-03T10:33:06.408562115Z for labelValues=[]string{"executing", "readOnly"}
```

Can someone please help me diagnose this issue.

Here are the list of versions:

- Vagrant : 2.2.14
- Ubuntu : 18.04.5 LTS
- Kubespray : 2.15.0
- kubernetes : 1.19.7

Comment: Can you try to install latest version of Kubernetes 1.20.4? Make sure you have choose proper network plugin - Vagrant uses flannel. Check if all requirements are met - https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray#requirements  https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/vagrant.md

Comment: Hi Vishak, welcome to S.F. [The issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/96459) doesn't mention it, but that behavior _(which is happening to your kernel, and k8s is just the victim)_ is almost certainly caused by extremely high load on your host OS, screwing up the virtualization's clock. I see the fix was pulled into _some_ release of 1.19 but the changelog doesn't cite it, so ideally you'd heed Malgorzata's advice and use a modern version. Good luck!

Comment: @VishakVinod Did you manage solve problem using our tips ?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get time to run it with 1.20.4. I will try it soon and let u knw about the result

Comment: @Malgorzata thanks for the advice.. it worked.. I changed the version to 1.20.4 and it worked.. kubespray latest version(2.15.0) officially dosent upport 1.20.4 so had to do some manual changes to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  solution install newest version of Kubernetes - `1.20.4`. Kubespray version officially support -   Kubernetes `v1.19.7` so small changes should be done before applying to adjust to Kubernetes version `1.20.4`.

Read: [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/), [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/vagrant.md).

Comment: @VishakVinod Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?